# Good performance with Accuracy but not with Dice loss in Image Segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

I'm doing image segmentation with U-Net like architecture on Tensorflow w/Keras but I'm new in Deep Learning.
I've got this dataset with the following set shapes:

- Train : X : (175250, 30, 30, 6) Y: (175250, 30, 30)
- Validation:  X: (29200, 30, 30, 6) Y: (29200, 30, 30)
- Test :  X: (29200, 30, 30, 6) Y: (29200, 30, 30)

Got some examples of these images and each channel, further down.

--> with 20% positive examples and 80% negative examples equally in each set

I run some series but for the best filter combination it made
the plot for BCE with good accuracy:
[image]

The plot for custom functions, Dice_Loss by Dice_Coeff:

[image]

And some images generated from the best model trained with test images:

[image]

The problem is when I change to dice loss and coefficient, there aren´t good predictions as we seen in the image plot and now it isn´t in the image prediction as we may see.
[image]

Why it performs so badly in the dice loss? What other function do you recommend?

My dice loss and coefficient function:

> ```
> def dice_coeff(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1):
>     intersection = K.sum(K.abs(y_true * y_pred), axis=-1)
>     return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(K.square(y_true),-1) + K.sum(K.square(y_pred),-1) + smooth)
>
>
> def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
>     return 1-dice_coeff(y_true, y_pred)
> ```

Comment: In my personal experience, dice loss works great with BCE for multi class segmentation. For binary segmentation, BCE performs better.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal What is BCE? Binary Cross Entropy?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using soft-dice?

Recent works in computer vision have proposed soft surrogates to alleviate discrepancies and directly optimize the desired metric, either through relaxations (soft-Dice, soft-Jaccard).

**There are other loss function that is popular for image segmentation:**

The most commonly used loss function for the task of image segmentation is a ***pixel-wise cross entropy loss***.
This loss examines each pixel individually, comparing the class predictions (depth-wise pixel vector) to our one-hot encoded target vector.

Another popular loss function for image segmentation tasks is based on the ***Dice coefficient***, (which you have tried already) which is essentially a measure of overlap between two samples. This measure ranges from 0 to 1 where a Dice coefficient of 1 denotes perfect and complete overlap.

In case you were wondering, there's a 2 in the numerator in calculating the Dice coefficient because our denominator "double counts" the common elements between the two sets. In order to formulate a loss function which can be minimized, we'll simply use 1−Dice.

This loss function is known as the ***soft Dice loss*** because we directly use the predicted probabilities instead of doing threshold and converting them into a binary mask.

A **soft Dice loss** is calculated for each class separately and then averaged to yield a final score. An example implementation is provided below.

```
def soft_dice_loss(y_true, y_pred, epsilon=1e-6): 
    """Soft dice loss calculation for arbitrary batch size, number of classes, and number of spatial dimensions.
    Assumes the `channels_last` format.
  
    # Arguments
        y_true: b x X x Y( x Z...) x c One hot encoding of ground truth
        y_pred: b x X x Y( x Z...) x c Network output, must sum to 1 over c channel (such as after softmax) 
        epsilon: Used for numerical stability to avoid divide by zero errors
    """
   
    # skip the batch and class axis for calculating Dice score
    axes = tuple(range(1, len(y_pred.shape)-1)) 
    numerator = 2. * np.sum(y_pred * y_true, axes)
    denominator = np.sum(np.square(y_pred) + np.square(y_true), axes)
    
    return 1 - np.mean(numerator / (denominator + epsilon)) # average over classes and batch
```

You may try this functions and find out what works best for your model.

Comment: On this article explain the same that you have copied and pasted in your answer: https://www.jeremyjordan.me/semantic-segmentation/

Comment: I keep struggling to get to work that soft dice loss. I receive the following error message: "NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (loss/conv2d_10_loss/mul:0) to a numpy array."

Comment: Thi definition is not gonna work because it is not written as a tensor.

Answer (score 0):

This is because most segmentation frameworks: minimizing loss functions (such as pixel-wise cross entropy) and subsequent *truncation at 0.5* or *argmax*, are designed for pixel-wise classification accuracy.

However, the commonly-used objective of segmentation is the Dice (or IoU) metric, and these classification-based frameworks naturally cannot ensure satisfactory results based on the Dice metric. My recent paper in JMLR (https://www.jmlr.org/papers/v24/22-0712.html) has proven that for Dice-segmentation, the correct approach should be: (1) rank the estimated pixel probabilities; (2) determine the number of segmented pixels for each image through computations, see Page 6 in the [paper](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/v24/22-0712.html).

Intuitively, Dice is a metric with a certain global property. It necessitates the handling of segmentation prediction on a global scale (the decision to choose a pixel for segmentation depends on its probability, while also considering the overall distribution of other pixels.), instead of simply truncating each pixel individually and independently at 0.5 like pixel-wise classification.

---

See more details:

- Paper: https://www.jmlr.org/papers/v24/22-0712.html
- Github: https://github.com/statmlben/rankseg
- Slides: https://slides.com/statmlben/rankseg